# RecycleBin Not Loading

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

I have a user who deleted thousands of documents and in that site collection's Recycle Bin, I get this error

> The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before
> 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use
> waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle.

I have to view these documents but the page RecycleBin.aspx won't load. Same story for the second-stage recycle bin. What's going on in this site that doesn't happen in others. Any random site recycle bin will load quickly but this one hangs for some reason. Any ideas of this error or how I can view the contents of the recycle bin maybe via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view the recycle bin items via PnP PowerShell.

`Get-PnPRecycleBinItem` is the command to view the files in the recycle bin.

To restore the items, you can use the `Restore-PnPRecycleBinItem` command.

For example -

`Get-PnPRecycleBinItem | ? -Property LeafName -like "*.docx" | Restore-PnpRecycleBinItem`
`

This command will restores all the items from the first and second stage recycle bins to their original location of which the filename ends with the .docx extension

If you hit the threshold issue, use the `RowLimit` parameter to overcome it.

References:

[Get-PnPRecycleBinItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnprecyclebinitem?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Restore-PnPRecycleBinItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/restore-pnprecyclebinitem?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I can't use any of these cmdlets because of the threshold. When specifying the RowLimit, I get this error => Get-PnPRecycleBinItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'RowLimit'.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, any chance you could be using the older version of PnP ? This parameter was added recently, if so, could you please update to the latest version and check ?